# How do I assign multiple badges to my community users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature-upgrade, community, multi-select

I'm currently working on the development of a SharePoint Community Site.
I've made some changes to display graphical rather than textual badges. Right now it only shows one badge. That's because you can only assign a single badge to the user.

How do I go about modifying the default column or badging system to allow me to assign multiple badges to a user?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't have more than one badge per user